# Error when export Excel using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll COM to export excel. I distribute my application to clients. It runs well on my computer but on another computer, it cause a error.

I wonder that application package should be included Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll and the computer must be installed Microsoft Excel. Thanks.

P/S: My application is C# .net 2.0.

UPDATE: I am having a problem. I don't know  the excel's version on the client computer. So, which version of PIA I will use?

If I build my application with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll version 11 (suitable with Office 2003), but what problem will happen if the client computer have Office 2007. It will run or no? How to use only one Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll which run well on any client computers which have one of office 2003, 2007 or 2010.

Thanks.

Comment: What error? What version of Excel on your computer/their computer? Did you use early or late binding?

Comment: You should create a new question for your new questions, that way more people will see it and answer it. However, If you use Late Binding you don't have to worry too much about what version of Excel it is (as long as you're not using some feature that only exist in some versions of course). Look at this link for more info regarding Late vs Early binding: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302902

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you deploy the other necessary DLL's?

- Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core.dll
- Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll

EDIT:

You should see two references in your project: *Microsoft.Office.Core* and *VBIDE*. Click on these references and set the property "Local Copy" to true.

A complete refrence to installing and deploying the PIA can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa159923%28office.11%29.aspx

On that website is also a link to a redistributable file you can include and run from your installer to install the PIA into the GAC.

Comment: I only deploy Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll. Please help me the purpose of 2 those files. Thanks.

Comment: @Lu Lu: The Office 2003 PIA is compatible to newer versions of Office, so the 2003 PIA should work with Office 2007 and 2010 without any change.

Comment: Hello, I have 2 questions: 1. How to detect client computer using office excel 2003 or office excel 2007 or no office excel. Assume that the client computer has a version of office excel, I will use which version of PIA to add reference to my project, and my application can run well and not depend on the version of excel on client. Which DLLs I can include in my application, and the client don't need to install PIA. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Office Automation you should always have Office installed. That's because the interop classes will create an instance of excel in the background and run all your actions on that instance.

If there is no office installed, it will thus not run properly. Please also keep in mind that using office automation on a server isn't the way to go (due to security issues and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Are they using the same version of Excel? you could look into the PIA (Primary Interop Assembiles) to deploy with your app.